# Problems with history.go

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So i'm developing an app, and, in the frontend i'm using react.js, and i got stuck at this.

**Problem**: I'm using history.go in a component to redirect to a different page, but if i use it more than once, it won't work..

Let me show you the code

Here i use it

```
<PresentationImg
              style={{ width: "100%", maxHeight: "50px" }}
              area="perfil"
            >
              <PersonalImgBorder>
                <PersonalImg
                  onClick={() => history.go(`/profile/${singlePhoto.creator}`)}
                  style={{
                    backgroundImage: `url(${singlePhoto.presentation})`,
                    backgroundSize: "cover",
                    backgroundPosition: "center",
                    border: "3px solid white",
                    cursor: "pointer"
                  }}
                />
              </PersonalImgBorder>
            </PresentationImg>
```

And i use it in the same component as well here

```
<PresentationImg
                    style={{ width: "100%", maxHeight: "50px" }}
                    area="perfil"
                  >
                    <CommentPresentation>
                      <img
                        src={comment.presentation}
                        onClick={() => {
                          history.go(`/profile/${comment.creator}`);
                        }}
                      />
                    </CommentPresentation>
                  </PresentationImg>
```

**Goal**: So, the second time i used it, it literally doesn't work, it redirects me to the first url ( the first time i used it ), so, why if i have more than 1 history.go, only the first one will work ?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history.go()` is used to [go forwards or backwards in history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/go), not to redirect to a specific page.

Use `history.push()` instead of `history.go()`, e.g.

```
history.push(`/profile/${comment.creator}`);
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll change my code then !

But, is it wrong doing historyg.go(url) ?

Comment: Yes. `history.go(-1)` is the same as `history.back()` and `history.go(1)` is the same as `history.forward()`

Answer (score 1):

`history.go` will move the pointer in the history stack by n entries. You can read more in here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history

In your case. I think uou should use `history.push`:

```
`history.push(`/profile/${comment.creator}`);`
```

Comment: Thank you so much broh !

But, it's wrong doing historyg.go(url) ?